# Java library project - package by layer vs feature

Tags: java

I've been reading different articles and posts about how package by feature is a better approach than package by layer. A lot of the reasons make sense to me, but I was wondering if I have a library project where I don't necessary need the package-private scope, does it make sense to package by feature?

My current layout is:

```
com.myproject.domain
    User
    Address
com.myproject.dto
    UserDto
com.myproject.repositories
    UserRepository
    AddressRepository
com.myproject.services
    UserService
    RepositoryUserService
    AddressService
    RepositoryAddressService
com.myproject.util
    UserUtil
```

The structure was packaged like this because it was to separate out the layers for implementation with `JPA`.

Comment: Maybe this question is more something for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @mhlz: I'm not sure what's being asked here.  Until that's clarified, I don't think it's on-topic anywhere.  Seems like an opinion-based question to me.

Comment: It doesn't really matter much - users usually don't care where a class is located.